# how to display the legend when the map contains external icons in R

Tags: r, legend, icon

I haven't found anything about the legend when the map contains icons external R (in png), is't possible to use the legend function or another function in R.

Comment: I don't know much about using **R** but this [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-use-external-image-with-R-plot-td4635959.html) might help?

Comment: @Joseph I managed to put my pictures on my external map thanks to the disscussion http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118286/is-it-possible-to-create-a-scatterplot-with-icons-svg-or-png-instead-of-points, now I want a method to my legend with icons

Comment: I could only find a related [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430855/incorporating-an-image-as-legend-for-ggplot2-plot). If this doesn't help then hopefully others will advise.